# Openfire XMPP Bot over Channels

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, openfire, chatbot

I am using Openfire as an XMPP server for building a customer support Bot framework.

I am planning to make use of channels/groups for the same. I am keen to use channels as there might be multiple human agents and a bot listening to the same conversation. So I am likely to have a group/channel for each individual.

I want the messages to be read and processed by my custom server. How do I go about this ? I couldn't find any plugin that allows me to intercept the messages and return back processed response.

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create your an own openfire bot plugin if you are familiar with Java (small example: https://rmsol.de/2018/03/06/Openfire_Bot/). Otherwise create bot as a client lilke dontknow suggested (The "bot/client" will join every channel you like and e.g. listen for specific keywords)

Comment: thanks @Roman S. I will try out the interceptor plugin as well and see. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that since Openfire is an XMPP Communication software, its best to just use a custom XMPP client ( on your own server ) to listen to all the messages and process it from there and reply back from the XMPP Client as well.

So if I have a Nodejs server, I will create a Node XMPP Client and listen to XMPP messages coming via Openfire from other users, will process them and reply back with custom messages which Openfire will send back to the user.